# How to apply GUI Skin to UI components created from the menu in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

In Unity, I have buttons and labels already created. Those elements were not created using script, so how to apply GUI Skin to UI components created from the menu not from the Script?

Comment: If you are using the new UI, it isn't super easy to do.  I am currently trying to work on solving this so far my only solution is to create prefabs of each element that you want and to create them at runtime from the prefab.  So in essence the prefab becomes the GUI skin.

Answer (score 0):

The buttons and Labels have a constructor that accepts your GUISkin [GUI.Button](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html)